# PHP xpath result as array of strings

Tags: php, arrays, xpath

I have seen several similar questions, but not found the exact answer I'm looking for. It may be that the functionality I am looking for does not exist.

If I do an xpath query that results in an array of objects, but each object only holds one value, a string, I'd like to quickly convert that into an array of strings. Obviously I can do a foreach on the object and push the string value onto a new array, but if there is a built in function I'm not thinking of, please let me know.

example:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#24 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(20) "Network Media Player"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#25 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "Music Player"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#26 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "Juke Box"
  }
}
```

I'd like that to become

```
array('Network Media Player','Music Player','Juke Box')
```

Comment: What does your XPath look like? Have you tried tagging `/text()` on to the end?

Comment: Yes. The result is still an array of objects. `$result=$parsed->xpath('/ItemSearchResponse/Items/Item/ItemAttributes/ProductGroup/text()'` From php.net: _Returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects or FALSE in case of an error._ So no matter what, I'm going to start with an array of objects. I'm just looking for the most efficient way of dealing with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my test :

```
<pre><?php 

$xml = "<data>
            <item>
                <value>Network Media Player</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <value>Music Player</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <value>Jukebox Player</value>
            </item>
        </data>";
$sx = simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r($sx);

print_r(explode("|",implode("|",$sx->xpath("//data/item/value"))));

?></pre>
```

and here's the result : http://codepad.org/ZkaWpzMc